# Adding Hyperlink to Dynamic Cell

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm stuggaling with getting to grips with adding hyperlinks to cells through vba. I think I have the pre-requists for adding of hyperlinks. Although I'm unable to get it to work.

Having looked through forums and the such, I was able to create this code, but no matter how hard I try I am unable to get it to work. The code produces `Object required` on the `.Hyperlink` line

```
        With ActiveWorksheet

            .Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=ActiveWorksheet.Cells(i, 2)
            Address = Cells(SerialNumberLocation, 2)
            TextToDisplay = AlternateEngineNumber

        End With
```

Do anyone have any tips on imporving the code?

By changing `ActiveWorkSheets` to `ActiveSheets` and removing the `.Hyperlink` to `Hyperlink` I still recive the same error, with the code nwo looking like

```
        With ActiveSheet

            Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)_
            Address = Cells(SerialNumberLocation, 2)_
            TextToDisplay = AlternateEngineNumber

        End With
```

Thanks

Comment: It is `Hyperlinks.Add` and you need line continuation characters for a statement that is spread over more than one line.

Comment: With ActiveSheet

Comment: ... line continuations and commas. (If, however ,this is not your real code, then you can see the issues that arise when you don't post exactly.)

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I've change to what you said although, i still get the same error

Comment: @AndyG I've posted the code as it is in the macro. Not quite sure what your getting at with Line coninuations character, do you mean things like `_)`??

Comment: Yes, an underscore is the line continuation character.

Comment: So it should look like the new edit? Have i got that right?

Comment: @AndyG All i get when i try to use the `_` in VBA is invlaid charetecter error

Comment: You need to purchase a book or take a tutorial as it is clear that you do not understand any information that you have been provided with here.

Comment: Can you recommend any?

Comment: Excel VBA for Dummies by John Walkenbach is excellent.

Comment: `Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)_`
`Address:=Cells(SerialNumberLocation, 2)_`
`TextToDisplay:=AlternateEngineNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Sub dural()
    i = 1
    SerialNumberLocation = 9
    AlternateEngineNumber = "Hello"
    With ActiveSheet
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(i, 2), _
                Address:=.Cells(SerialNumberLocation, 2).Value, _
                TextToDisplay:=AlternateEngineNumber
    End With
End Sub
```

Please take special notice of the **colons** and the **periods**

[image]